# python resolve module name conflict when imported module name is not well defined

Tags: python, python-import, project-management, python-module

I've googled a lot but couldn't find the answer, I've tried methods such as relative import, using alias(in current project or in imported modules **init** file).
To help reproduce it easily, I checked the demo code in [github](https://github.com/LeiYangGH/py-import-conflict).

The repo has two folders, **A** and **B**. they are considered as **different projects created by different developers**. I put them into one single git repo becuase it is easier for you just for **demo purpose**.

Files list:

.
├── A
│   ├── **init**.py
│   ├── foo_a.py
│   └── utils_module
│         ├── **init**.py
│         └── utils.py
├── B
│   ├── **init**.py
│   ├── main.py
│   └── utils_module
│         ├── **init**.py
│         └── utils.py
└── README.md

Both A and B has its main entrance and can run successfully(just referencing its utils and then echo A or B).

Now the question is, A has some function(`foo_a`) that can (but not designed to) be reused by B, and so B needs to import it. But I don't want to merge the two projects into one because they are developed seperately. And refactoring A's folder/package structure is also not in this question's scope(except adding some code in **init**, if it helps). You ask me why, I'm just learning the importing mechanism of python.

To be able to import A in B, I use `sys.path.append(A's relative or absolute path)`. But when running B, it gives error:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'echo_a'.

The error is reasonable, because both A and B have the same module named `utils_module/utils`(which I don't want to change either), and seems `utils` in B has overriden that of A.

If add `__init__` file in A, and add import prefix `A.` in both B.main.py and use relative import (`from .`) in A.foo_a.py then running B can get correct output . But this time A cannot run as before, error

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '**main**.utils_module';
> '**main**' is not a package

So how to solve this, by changing the importing syntax? Thanks!

Comment: One way is to split it into 3 projects and make 3rd one "common" module for both, containing `foo_a`.

Comment: thanks, your way is somehow good. but that is adding a dependency. A and B can currently work on themselves, and I like it.

Comment: Can you clarify what you are struggling with? As shown, the modules are actually ``A.utils`` and ``B.utils`` (and likewise ``A.foo_a`` and ``B.main``) so there is no conflict. Are the "packages" actually designed to be entirely top-level? If-so, fixing them upstream is the most reasonable course of action.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi when using `sys.path.append()` in B the importing of utils module would just be `import utils` (or `from utils import echo_a`), which clashes with it's own utils. Both the current directory and the directory of B have a top level module named utils

Comment: @MisterMiyagi i don't understand your question well. the two projects are seperately designed, they are designed to not be imported by other code. so no package name(or maybe your **top-level** packages means the same thing?). if i create a project that will never be used by other project, it seems pointless to define a package name to me. and I'm not trying to refactor the project structure, becuase I'm just asking about the possiblity and the syntax, for educational and learning purpose, the simplest solution is merge A and B into one common module. but that is not the topic here.

Comment: *No* package lives in isolation, even if just due to the existence of the standard library. This question would not exist if "project that will never be used by other project" would actually never be used by other projects. Fixing the package layout is the proper solution to handling package layout problems. If necessary we can of course advise how to fix the issue with a bandaid to respect certain practical restrictions (e.g. the packages being non-modifiable) but please understand that people will want to doublecheck such a fragile solution is actually what is needed before advising so.

Comment: i think the use case is reasonable, a project has some useful piece of code that can be reused, but it is not owned by me. i have no write access. but still i want to reuse that code. and there's naming conflict by coincidence. ^_^

Comment: I am not concerned whether it is a reasonable use-case (I know it is by necessity) – by now mostly whether it is a *real* use-case, or a purely academic one. In a practical use-case, there usually are various sharp edges from the imperfect package encapsulation; the solution depends strongly on these. Are the namespaces of ``A.utils`` and ``B.utils`` separate or would there be conflicts when merging? Can the packages be imported one after the other, or do the packages have other conflicts? Does any package perform introspection of paths or imports? Is any package compiled?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi i'm afraid i cannot answer so many questions in comments. in fact `utils` is the only name that A and B have in common, they have different contents of course. every developer would think of `utils` or `helpers` right? `introspection`? i don't understand this word and by googling i think there isn't any. all i need is solving the problem as the code in github demonstrates. no package compiled.

Answer (score 1):

You would want to treat A and B as packages - so in each folder (A and B) you would add a completely empty file named `__init__.py`.

Then in B you would uniquely identify A's utils module with something like

```py
from A.utils import echo_a
```

When you just added each directory to the path then yes, the utils module was overridden by whichever was found first by the interpreter. Structuring in to packages is one way to modularize isolated pieces of code.

Then the way you run this would be from the directory above A and B, you run something like `python -m B.main`

---

If things are really built out you could also build up a setup.py for each of A and B and make it so one can install the other using pip.

Comment: thanks. i created a branch [A-as-module](https://github.com/LeiYangGH/py-import-conflict/tree/A-as-module) demonstration your solution. the problem is, i have to change A's code to reflect the package name change, i have to use `from A.utils import echo_a` in foo_a.py, otherwise running B.main.py will throw exception. I don't want to change A's code other than adding __init__ file. from project A's perspective, it looks useless to name the whole package.

Comment: It is common to have to import things from your own package including it's own package name. It's a nice encapsulation of the project A package files. You could alter the import to be a relative import: `from .utils import echo_A` - but it's tricky to treat A like a package for others but not for itself

Comment: your solution can solve B importing A, but now A itself got this error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'main.utils_module'; 'main' is not a package`. please see my updated code.